# Code refactoring for integration four projects to one project

Tags: java, json, refactoring, request, response

I am starting code refactoring for integrating four small projects to one project,the four projects is very similar.
the general logic of the project is as this:a http-server to receive the request,the request is as a json format,for example **A(we call A has two objects: a_key, b_key)**:

```
 {a_key : a_value, b_key : {bb_key: {b_key1 : b_value1}}}
```

but the four types of request is not the same, there is a little different between them. for example: the second project receive request as this **B(we call B has three objects: a_key, c_key, d_key)**:

```
 {a_key : a_value, c_key : {cc_key: {c_key1 : c_value1}}，d_key: [dd1, dd2, dd3]}
```

just as the above, all the requests is in JSON format, the different is "some key" may have a different name(eg: bb_key, cc_key), and the parameter count may be different(eg: **B has dd_key parameter**).I can't be sure the concrete parameter's names and counts.
Also, all the responses are in JSON format, but as requests, a little different between them.  The process is similar, according to the parameter, after some filters, the response is returned.

I think the difficult of refactoring of this is **a general of Request and Response**, now in our four projects, most of the code is similar, but a little different for Request and Response, our code use Java, we use Jackson to translate every request, **we define a concrete class for every object in the request(eg: a_key, b_key, c_key, d_key). I don't want define so many objects class for the 4 type requests, since there is only one or two parameter different.** now I have no idea to general this Request, any guy has ideas? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In generic class, convert your json parameters into HashMap. Implement [Factory Design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) such that Factory class will return appropriate filter based on whether required key is present in HashMap or not. Use the returned filter to process your result and return JSON response.

Comment: yeah, at first, I want to save the json parameters in hashmap, but that means I do the same job as Jackson, Jackson is used to analysis and translate Json, I don't want to do the same job.do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I don't clearly get you.. Jackson is used to translate JSON string in java objects and object suggested here is hashmap.. do u want to parse keys directly in string

Comment: i got you! but for hashmap<key, object>, for every object, i should define a concrete class.since there is a little different between the request parameter.so anyway,I should define a Java class to store the parameter in Request, so, I need define four concrete class?